# Function to check total value

Tags: javascript

I want to check the total value in the calculator so that i can show an answer as a chemical formula for example after pressing O which has value of "9" and adding C with value of "8" i would get 17 and i want to make a function that would detect the value and say something in these lines: "You've created CO2"
I just want some directions or a pointer because i really want to learn and i'm still a newbie anyway here's the calculator:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var inputs=[""];
      var totalString;
      var operator1 = ["+"];
      var operator2 = ["."];
      var nums=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    function getValue(input){
     if(inputs.length===1 && operator1.includes(input)===false){
        inputs.push(input);
      }
      else if(operator1.includes(inputs[inputs.length-1])===false){
        inputs.push(input);
      }
      else if(nums.includes(Number(input))){
        inputs.push(input);
      }
    update();
    }
      function update(){
          totalString= inputs.join("");
        $("#steps").html(totalString);
      }
      function getTotal(){
         totalString= inputs.join("");
        console.log(totalString + ": " + eval(totalString));
        $("#steps").html(eval(totalString));
      }
      
      $("a").on("click",function(){
        if(this.id==="deleteAll"){
          inputs = [""];
          update();
        }
        else if(this.id==="backOne"){
          inputs.pop();
          update();
        }
        else if(this.id==="total"){
          getTotal();
        }
        else{
          if(inputs[inputs.length-1].indexOf("+")===-1){
            getValue(this.id);
          }
          else {
            getValue(this.id);
          }
        } 
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text-center">
      
    </div>
    <div id ="calcOutput">
      <span id= "steps"></span>
      <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center"
         id="calculator">
      <a class="btn btn-danger" 
         id="deleteAll">AC</a>
      <a class="btn btn-danger"
         id="backOne">CE</a>
      <br/>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="7"
          id="7">H</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="8"
          id="8">O</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="9"
          id="9">C</a>
      <br/>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="4"
          id="4">N</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="5"
          id="5">F</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="6"
          id="6">S</a>
      <br/>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="1"
          id="1">Fe</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="2"
          id="2">Na</a>
       <a class="btn btn-primary"
          value="3"
          id="3">Cl</a>
      <br/>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="total">=</a>
      <a class ="btn btn-primary bigButton" id="+">+</a>
    </div>
```

Thank you for any help, and every other comments!

Comment: Yes it is working but i want to make a function that would find the total value for example when the total value = 17 send an alert that says "You've created CO2" But i just don't know how to and i was hoping that somebody would help.

Comment: but it's simples, inside your  `getTotal()` function, you have the value, right? from there, just add a call to another funciton that emits the alert, somenthing like `myAlert(pass the value here as parameter)`, then create `function myAlert(value){//code for alert}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the approach.
Are you trying to map 17 to CO2 ? If that is the case then there could be number of ways to produce 17, like FE+O+O = (1+8+8)= 17, that may not be the result you are expecting. I would say to maintain an array(map) of compounds like co2,o2 etc.
And then append the text instead of adding number while keypress.
Eg: user press C + O, then check in the array with all compounds having CO.